# Is Norway spruce (Picea abies (L.) Karst.) isohydric or anisohydric species?

Tags: physiology, plant-physiology

Question from a thesis defense list ask me this. But I can't find the exact answer on the internet or in books. In my thesis, I described isohydric plants, for example maize, lupin, pea, poplar. This plants response to a decrease in soil water in same way. How Norway spruce response to decrease in soil water? As a isohydric plant or anisohydric?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE. Please Edit your question and re-post it, with little more details.

Comment: What do you think and why?

Comment: According to [this report](http://era.deedi.qld.gov.au/3052/1/Iso-anisohydric_vegetable_report_PR09-4248-sec.pdf), maize, lupin, pea, and poplar are all *anisohydric*.

Comment: @augurar According [this study:](http://jxb.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2013/02/14/jxb.ert029.full) 

> For this reason, in these species leaf water potential is a better indicator of soil moisture than gs. Isohydric species (e.g. maize, lupin, pea, poplar), on the other hand, close their stomata in response to a decrease in soil water and/or an increase in VPD, controlling plant water potential.

Comment: @Hawk81 I think you are right and that was a mistake in the report I linked -- one of the papers they cite lists maize and poplar as isohydric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This review paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00468-014-1035-9) states that spruce is isohydric, citing *Physiologie und Ökologie der Gehölze* by Lyr, Fiedler, & Tranquillini:

> Spruce appears to reﬂect an isohydric strategy (Lyr et al. 1992), reducing stomatal conductance at early stages of soil drought.

It's important to note that this is not a binary distinction, isohydric and anisohydric are two extremes in a spectrum of how plants respond to drought.